# How to upload a background image using actionscript 3.0 code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

**Need your help. I am trying it first time.**

I have used following code.
But i get this in my console:

**started loading file
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.**

and my image url is in same folder as my script file.

`var loader:Loader = new Loader();`

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\23Aug\demo1\mic.jpg"), context);
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
trace("started loading file");
addChild(loader);
function fileLoaded(event:Event):void
{
trace("file loaded");
}
```

Comment: You can't load a local file like that. Use a relative path, see if that fixes it. Also, you are not using your context for anything (nor should it be needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons to throw securityError exception.

- Invalid path,
- Trying to access a URL, that not permitted by the security sandbox,
- Trying a socket connection, that exceeding the port limit, and
- Trying to access a device, that has been denied by the user(Ex., camera, microphone.)

try this

```
private var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
private var _context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
private var _url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("demo1/mic.jpg");

_context.checkPolicyFile = false;
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageloaded);
//_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
_loader.load(_url, _context);
private function onImageloaded(e:Event):void{
    addChild(e.target.content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slashes instead of back slashes :

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("C:/Documents and Settings/Owner/Desktop/23Aug/demo1\mic.jpg"), context);
```

But the best way is to use relative path like "./mic.jpg" and do not use absolute path.